# Best way to test an insert and get success/error without committing?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a PHP script that does a batch import of data into a table, and I want to have a "test mode" where the system processes the INSERT statements and notes if there are any errors on any of the statements, but does not commit the data to the table.

What is the best way to execute an INSERT to get either success or mysql_error() without having the actual operation be permanent?

For example:

```
    $r=mysql_query($cmd);
    if ($r) { 
        $rownote.=" ADDED";
        $addcount++;
    } else { 
        $merror=mysql_error();
        $rownote.=" ERROR: (<FONT SIZE=\"-1\">$merror</FONT>)";
        $failcount++;
    }
```

I want to be able to execute the above in a "test mode" and generate the rownotes, but not actually execute the statements.  Should I use some sort of rollback?  Or is there a way I can specify an insert statement that would not do the actual insert but return whether or not the INSERT would be successful or the error?

Comment: You could create a complex function to validate the string, making checks for all the thing that MySQL syntax allows and does not allow and return accordingly

Comment: the simplest way would be just to execute the statements, if you do it as a transaction then you can roll it back afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution that works.  (I am aware that some people don't like using mysql_query and it is depreciated, but this is a legacy app I'm having to modify).

```
        if ($ftestmode) {
            mysql_query("SET AUTOCOMMIT=0");
            mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");
        }

        $r=mysql_query($cmd);
        if ($r) { 
            $rownote.=" ADDED";
            $addcount++;
        } else { 
            $merror=mysql_error();
            $rownote.=" ERROR: (<FONT SIZE=\"-1\">$merror</FONT>)";
            $failcount++;
        }
        $errors[]=$rownote;
        if ($ftestmode) {
            mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
        }
```